# Netflow application ID to application name

Tags: filebeat, netflow

Im getting netflow data from multiples machines using filebeat, one of the fields I get is `netflow.application_id` and I need to transate the Id to the name of the application, the format of the application_id is this:
`3, 0, 1, 244`
four comma separated values.
how I can translate the id to a name?
is there a dictionary out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a script processor to split the values in the network.application_id field and then do a lookup to append the values accordingly. This is definitely an option, but not necessarily the only option. Feel free to accept this answer if it works for you.